# Entity Code first, where is my DB file stored?

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, entity, ef-code-first

Using Entity 4.1 for a project, and couldn't figure out where the DB file been stored inside my project.

I think I've read that Entity code first will still store your data in SQL Express DB at a default location, but couldn't find out where it is.

What I did is:

1. create Entity DB project (Project A) in my solution, this project will have an Initializer to generate sample data for testing.
2. I also create a separate project (Project B) to save my Entity Code first data for testing by another application.
3. Then I create another WinForm project(Project C) in the same solution, and access DBContext from Project A.

I would assume that the DB should be somewhere in my Project C, and test projects in the solution shouldn't make a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a default installation of SQL Server Express and no connection string the database will be created in the DATA directory of the installation, for example something like: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA` (for 2008 R2 version). The name of the database is `namespace.contextname`, for example: `MyNamespace.MyContext.mdf` (and .ldf). Under this name you can also find them in SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: thank you, I found it under the path like you specified, the only difference is I changed my SQL Server to different name. I should find it earlier if I am using VS's DB Server explorer. Not sure why, but I was assuming that Entity Code first will create local DB file under my project but not create a DB on my default SQL Server. Yeah, why Entity create a DB automatically for me on my Local SQL Server?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an ancient thread covering a different scenario, but google directed me here when I was trying to figure this out for a UWP app, so if anybody follows in my footsteps, here's my solution.

If you're using entity with sqlite in a windows app, your database file will likely be created in the "working directory" of your app. In this case it's:

```
C:\Users\<Username>\Local\Packages\{Package-Name}\LocalState\
```

you can find your {Package-Name} by looking in the app manifest. It'll probably be a long string of numbers and letters by default.

[image]